# Implementation of FTP using BSD sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I need to write a program in BSD sockets which behaves like a file transfer protocol for transferring file contents. It has to use two TCP connections between client and server.

If not code, please provide any other reference material such as flowchart or algorithm for the implementation.

Comment: Why not just use an existing FTP API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going through the FTP documentation available [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) .

Answer (score 1):

If you need to adhere to the historical FTP implementation, [ard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560834/377270) should be helpful. Be sure that your implementation does not suffer from the [FTP bounce vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP_bounce_attack) that allows attackers to 'hide' their IP address when performing TCP port scans.

However, I'd like to suggest that the two-connection approach is the wrong one -- it makes NAT traversal significantly more complicated. Furthermore, since the historical FTP specification does not specify the directory listing format, it is more difficult to parse with the intention of creating graphical tools (and human readers can be confused).

The [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) protocol does not suffer these problems. Of course, it is also significantly more complicated; however, it can traverse NAT firewalls far more reliably and it provides for unambiguous parsing.